# Source or input or include Rmd file in a Rnw document

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, article, rnw

I am trying to write my paper and using Elsevier document class as a `Rnw` document. I also tried to use `rticle` package which I find little difficult to customise. Is it possible to include `Rmd` file in my `Rnw` document so that I can use the `Rnw` frame and also use my `Rmd` chapters for other purposes like comple it to HTML.

Comment: It's not quite the same, but can you just compile the `Rmd` files to latex and source them in that form?

Comment: For now, I have found a solution,
http://svmiller.com/blog/2016/02/svm-r-markdown-manuscript/
I think the solution is very good one. I will be following this.

Comment: For the record (and anyone else with a similar question), is it worth posting as either (a) an edit to the question, indicating a temporary workaround, or (b) as a self-provided answer with one working alternative?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans), I want to post what I have found as an answer to my own question. It is not a direct answer to my question but I will be following this for now. Instead of using Rnw file, Rmd file can use `tex` template. The process is described in [this site](http://svmiller.com/blog/2016/02/svm-r-markdown-manuscript/).